# HtmlUnit 400 Bad Request when additional Host header is set

Tags: java, htmlunit

I need to use a browser that can be run from Java program and allows to send a custom HTTP request directly and modify any part of the HTTP request. Therefore I chose HtmlUnit.

I tried to make a simple GET request to `http://localhost` and added an additional header `Host:localhost`. The page on my localhost home is XAMPP home. Inside the page, there is a request to other site (facebook.com). If the Host header is added, I got `400 Bad Request error`. The error doesn't happen if I don't add Host header.

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 400 Bad Request for http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=277385395761685
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:894)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:775)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:751)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:739)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:910)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:307)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:368)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:781)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:738)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1243)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1143)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:226)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:345)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3154)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2117)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:945)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:521)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:472)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:988)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:246)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:267)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:155)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:517)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:391)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:473)
```

In HtmlUnit, is all additional headers are applied on all request on the page (not only the first URL)?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

No, additional requests are not applied to other requests.

Below is a complete case, compare it with yours:

index.html:

```
First
<a href="index2.html">test</a>
```

index2.html

```
Second
```

Test case:

```
LogManager.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(Level.ALL);
final CollectingAlertHandler handler = new CollectingAlertHandler();
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
    WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("http://localhost:8080"));
    request.setAdditionalHeader("Host", "abc.com");
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);
    page.getAnchors().get(0).click();
}
```

Output:

```
DEBUG 08:07:31,868 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "GET / HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,869 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: abc.com[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,869 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,869 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,869 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,869 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,869 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Language: en-US[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,870 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,873 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 [\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,873 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Accept-Ranges: bytes[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,873 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "ETag: W/"37-1491113233075"[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,873 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Last-Modified: Sun, 02 Apr 2017 06:07:13 GMT[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,873 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: text/html[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,873 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 37[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,875 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Sun, 02 Apr 2017 06:07:31 GMT[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,875 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,875 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "First[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:31,875 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "<a href="index2.html">test</a>"
DEBUG 08:07:32,172 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "GET /index2.html HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,172 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,172 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,172 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,172 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,173 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Referer: http://localhost:8080/[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,173 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,173 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Language: en-US[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,173 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,174 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 [\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,174 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Accept-Ranges: bytes[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,174 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "ETag: W/"6-1491113144011"[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,174 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Last-Modified: Sun, 02 Apr 2017 06:05:44 GMT[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,174 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: text/html[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,175 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 6[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,175 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Sun, 02 Apr 2017 06:07:31 GMT[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,175 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG 08:07:32,175 org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 << "Second"
```